# i want to display the subdirectory instead of the files. where to change in the code?

Tags: php

[php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNZbX.png)

kindly see the code image and let me know where to change to display the directory instead of the files. plus I want to display the directory in the select box.

Comment: Please add your code to the question and explain what you have already tried.

Comment: You can change your code to `$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
print_r( $dirs);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `glob` with `GLOB_ONLYDIR` flag, i.e.:

```
$dirs_only = glob("/path/to/dir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR );
```